# Why do some people override the comparator function for implementing minheap using PriorityQueue even though PQ in java is a min-heap by default?

Tags: java, comparator, priority-queue, min-heap

I searched a bit and looks like a `PriorityQueue` work like a min-heap by default in Java. So, why override the comparator? I have seen people do it even for integers. Am I missing something here? I am new to java.

I tried both of the below codes to use in a leetcode solution requiring `min-heap` implementation and both got accepted. Here is a snippet:

```
// Implementing comparator
PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(10,new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a - b;
    }
});

// Not implementing comparator - why can't we just do this?
PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>();
```

Comment: a) they didn't know what they were doing and copy and pasted it from somewhere.
b) the did know what they were doing but wanted a reminder of which ordering it used by default

Comment: The only way to know why would be to ask *those people*. Any answer here would be speculation.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if there was some technical explanation that I did not know of.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the `Comparator` indeed seems redundant. If you don't explicitly pass a `Comparator` to `PriorityQueue`'s constructor, it will use natural ordering, which is exactly what this `Comparator` implements.

Comment: Not exactly. The comparator using `a - b` is obviously meant to do the same as the natural order, but actually is *broken*, as this subtraction can overflow. The maximum distance between two `int` values may exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. It might be that the author of this code even replaced the natural order by this deliberately, thinking of this being a “clever” optimization over the straight-forward `int` comparison, in which case, it might be a heavy task to break this developer’s habit…